# Deselcting a pre pupulated array swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a filter operation which is done on a bottom sheet and this value is then converted to a dictionary, I have a collectionView embeded in a UIView to display filter parameters.

When an item is selected and a `filter` button is pressed, I want to save the selected value using `UserDefault` so I can persist the searched Item if the user decides to go to the filter page again until the user press rest then I clear everything.

Currently my filter works as expected but my issue now is the persistence. When I preselect the cells, and I try to deselect that field, I get a crash.

Here's what I do

```
fileprivate let data1 = UserDefaultsConfig.contributionTypeFilter["selectedPaymentIndex"] as? Data
    var arrSelectedIndex = [IndexPath]() // This is selected cell Index array
    var arrSelectedData = [String]()

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
        let strData = PaymentMethodFilter.allCases[indexPath.item].rawValue.capitalized
        arrSelectedIndex.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        arrSelectedData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let strData = PaymentMethodFilter.allCases[indexPath.item].rawValue.capitalized
        arrSelectedIndex.append(indexPath)
        arrSelectedData.append(strData)
    }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeue(dequeueableCell: PaymentMethodFilterCollectionCell.self, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.feedSubviews(with: PaymentMethodFilter.allCases[indexPath.row])
        
        guard let selectedData = data1 else {
            return cell
        }
        arrSelectedData = UserDefaultsConfig.contributionTypeFilter["payment_method_names"] as? [String] ?? []
        arrSelectedIndex = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: selectedData) as? [IndexPath] ?? []
        arrSelectedIndex.forEach {
            collectionView.selectItem(at: $0, animated: true, scrollPosition: .right)
        }
        return cell
    }
```

> Fatal error: Index out of range: file
> /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift,
> line 1221 2020-08-16 15:36:26.359431+0100 Riby[40882:1056506] Fatal
> error: Index out of range: file
> /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift,
> line 1221

Comment: Share the crash logs as well.

Comment: It is an index out of range crash

Comment: Put a break point at the line of crash, and check the index value:s you are using to collect data from array/s.

Comment: Collect or index value  to remove

Answer (score 0):

> I want to save the selected value

To record what is selected, do not make an array of index paths, because index paths can change (and in your code, that's just what happens). Instead, make an array of *unique identifiers* for the data represented by the selected cells. That way, you can always find them again. What doesn't change is the data, so that's the way to identify things.

Basically, your underlying data model should consist of uniquely identifiable entries. (If you use a diffable data source, that rule will be enforced for you, which is just one many reasons why diffable data sources are great.) You can always convert between actual data objects and current cells in the collection view, in both directions.

Comment: the saved value are distinct strings. The crash occur if I try removing an item with the index path.

Plus I already set the indexpath to the fetched value from my `cellForItemAt indexPath`

Comment: I stand by my answer.

Comment: Okay, but at the point of populating the  selected cells, I need an indexPath to actually select those cells.

Comment: Yes, so you do what I just said. You look at the actual data objects and convert from them to the index paths of the cells that displays them, and select those cells. You know which data object it is so you can say, what index path is this data object _now_.